# Mathematica and Sympy is unable to simplify expressions such as log(e^A) to A, and errors involving for Integrating limtis to be real

Tags: python, numpy, sympy, wolfram-mathematica, topology

I am trying to implement a physics paper related to Quantum Computing. The part that I am implementing right now is done numerically. In this, I want to evolve the Hamiltonian H1 which is written in the momentum space (i.e in the reciprocal space - not a physical space). The hamiltonian expression is in the image below -
Equation S11 is the time evolution operator for H1
Equation above S13 is the effective hamiltonian Heff, which can be simplified using the equation S14
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKrEq.png)
U1(epsilon) is the periodized time evolution operator for 1D Topological Matter as given in S16
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riUEY.png)
S29 is the expression for winding number which has to be computed
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XX7Lv.png)

The ultimate goal is to implement this part and understand it. I have not got into the part for plotting this, but I can expect what values I should be obtaining for winding number for different values of alpha and beta - winding number will be zero only for alpha and beta, but I am getting it zero for any values that I am inputting into the expression in Mathematica.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9biP.png)

The errors that I am getting are -
Unable to prove the integrating limits are real {0, T/2}
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpb4f.png)
Another issue that I am facing is that, when I try plotting the winding number as a function of alpha and beta, its running for too long. The range of alpha and beta - -2 to +2.

I tried using Sympy for symbolic computation, but it is taking too long to compute.
Here is the Code for Sympy-

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy import random
# import scipy.integrate as integrate
from sympy import symbols, Matrix
import sympy as sp
from sympy import series

tau_x = np.array([[0.0, 1.0], [1.0, 0.0]])
tau_y = np.array([[0.0, complex(0.0, -1.0)], [ complex(0.0, 1.0), 0.0]])
tau_z = np.array([[1.0, 0.0], [0.0, -1.0]])
# alpha, beta, T, kx, e= 0, 0, 2, 0, 0.1
J_0, J_S, kx, e, T, alpha, beta = symbols('J_0, J_S, kx, e, T, alpha, beta')

J_0 = 3*alpha/(4*T)
J_S = 3*beta/(2*T)

#### Define H and Heff - figure out how this is different from Floquet Hamiltonian H

M1 = complex(0, -1)*sp.Matrix([[0, (J_0*T/3)+(J_S*T*np.exp(kx*complex(0,1))/6)],[(J_0*T/3)+(J_S*T*np.exp(kx*complex(0,1))/6),0]])
M2 =  (T/2)*complex(0, 1)*sp.Matrix([[2*np.pi/T, -(J_0*T/(3*np.log(e)))-(J_S*T*np.exp(kx*complex(0,1))/(6*np.log(e)))],[-(J_0*T/(3*np.log(e)))-(J_S*T*np.exp(kx*complex(0,1))/(6*np.log(e))),2*np.pi/T]])
```

Error in the Cell

```
from sympy import symbols
x, y = symbols('x,y')
a = x + 2*y
print(a*a)
(x + 2*y).subs({x:10, y:3})
```

Output of the above cell-

```
(x + 2*y)**2
16
 
ERROR! Session/line number was not unique in database. History logging moved to new session 223
```

Also, in numpy, I guess it does not exponentiate the matrix so that the final matrix evaluates close to the one obtained through Taylor Series Expansion, it simply takes exponent for each matrix element. Because exponentiating Identity matrix - np.exp([[1,0],[0,1]]) as [2.71, 1], [1, 2.71]

Is there any way which can be done using in-built function in python?

Here is the Mathematica Code that I wrote-

```
 pauliX[n_Integer] := 
 KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[n/2], {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}]

pauliY[n_Integer] := 
 KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[n/2], {{0, -I}, {I, 0}}]

pauliZ[n_Integer] := 
 KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[n/2], {{1, 0}, {0, -1}}]

(*Print[Dimensions[pauliX[8]]]*)
```

```
T=2*Pi

H1[t_,kx_, beta_, alpha_] := Piecewise[{{(3*alpha/(4*T*Pi))*pauliX[2], 0 <= t <= T/3}, {(3*beta/(2*T*Pi))*(Cos[kx]*pauliX[2]-Sin[kx]*pauliY[2]), T/3 <= t <= 2*T/3}, {(3*alpha/(4*T*Pi))*pauliX[2], 2*T/3 <= t <= T}}]
U1[t_, kx_, beta_, alpha_] := Exp[-I*Integrate[H1[t1, kx, beta, alpha], {t1, 0, t}]]
Heff[kx_, epil_, beta_, alpha_] := If[epil==Pi,(I/T)*((2*Pi*I)+(Log[(U1[T/2, kx, beta, alpha])])/Log[(epil)]),(I/T)*(-(2*Pi*I)-(Log[(U1[T/2, kx, beta, alpha])])/Log[(epil)])]
U1epil[t_, kx_, epil_, beta_, alpha_] := U1[t, kx, beta, alpha] . (Exp[(I*t*Heff[kx, epil, beta, alpha])])
K = Tr[pauliZ[2]*Inverse[U1epil[T/2, kx, epil, beta, alpha]]*(D[U1epil[T/2,Pi, Pi, 1.8*Pi, 1.8*Pi]])]
Print[FullSimplify[K]]
kx =.;
Plot[Tr[pauliZ[2]*Inverse[U1epil[T/2, kx, Pi, 1.8*Pi, 1.8*Pi]]*(D[U1epil[T/2, kx, Pi, 1.8*Pi, 1.8*Pi], kx])],{kx,-3.14,3.14}]
v[kx_, epil_, beta_, alpha_] := (I/(4*Pi))*Integrate[Tr[pauliZ[2]*Inverse[U1epil[T/2, kx, epil, beta, alpha]]*(D[U1epil[T/2, kx, epil, beta, alpha], kx])], kx, -Pi, Pi]
Print[FullSimplify[U1epil[T/2, kx, Pi, 1.8*Pi,1.8*Pi]]]
Print[v[kx,Pi, 1.8*Pi, 1.8*Pi]]
```

Errors-

```
Integrate: Invalid integration variable or limit(s) in -\[Pi].
General: -3.13987 is not a valid variable.
General: -3.13987 is not a valid variable.
General: -3.13987 is not a valid variable.
General: "Further output of General::ivar will be suppressed during this calculation"
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Mathematica is INTENSELY case sensitive. Change `log` to `Log` and `e` to `E` in that Mathematica code and edit your post to show exactly the individual lines of Mathematica code with the error message each is producing and I'll see if I can find any other simple fixes.

Comment: Regarding the python code, you haven't included nearly enough of the code to debug anything. Please provide enough of the code to reproduce the errors. If possible, please simplify it to only what's important and can still be run (i.e. a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)).

Comment: To many different questions.  A Mathematica one, a pure sympy, and a mixed sympy/numpy block.  The error in the simple sympy case is not a sympy problem.  That code, pasted to a new session runs fine.  The error talks about 'session/line number'.  You don't say anything about the running envirionment, though I'm guessing a jupyter notebook.  Mixing numpy and sympy is a bad idea - unless you understand both well.

Comment: @hpaulj the issue with sympy is resolved, I was using np.exp instead of sp.exp. Thanks!

Comment: @Bill when i am trying plot the integrand with the range varying from -3.14 to 3.14, i am getting this error "-3.14 is not a valid variable"

Comment: Here's the code -

`kx =.;
Plot[Tr[pauliZ[2]*Inverse[U1epil[T/2, kx, Pi, 1.8*Pi, 1.8*Pi]]*(D[U1epil[T/2, kx, Pi, 1.8*Pi, 1.8*Pi], kx])],{kx,-3.14,3.14}]`

Comment: Also I guess there could be issues with my approach. I wanted to ask if its possible to plot multivariate function where kx, alpha and beta are the variables, kx goes from -pi to pi and beta -2 to 2, alpha from -2 to 2. I was trying to extract the data for plot (a function of kx) using this code that I came across a StackOverflow answer - 
`kx=.; expr=Tr[pauliZ[2]*Inverse[U1epil[T/2,kx,Pi,1.8*Pi,1.8*Pi]](D[U1epil[T/2,kx,Pi,1.8*Pi,1.8*Pi], kx])]; data = Catenate@Cases[Plot[Re[expr],{kx,-Pi,Pi}],Line[data_] :> data, Pi];Export["file.txt", data, "Table"];ListPlot[Import["file.txt", "Table"]] `

Comment: The curve is -1.5 and 1.5, which is why the integral evaluates to zero.

Comment: Yep got it! I want to integrate the expr to find the winding number to confirm if the mathematical equations that I have used are correct. Also, I figured out some errors in the math expr. I updated the post with the new code.  The issue is that its not simplifying the final integral to give a definite value

Comment: Doing a complicated calculation inside of `Plot` and getting it exactly right requires that you know and do more things. Try doing the calculation before the plot and then plot that result. Do this with your code above by replacing `Plot[Tr[...]*(D[U1epil...]]` with `expr=Tr[pauliZ[2]*Inverse[U1epil[T/2,kx,Pi,1.8*Pi,1.8*Pi]]*(D[U1epil[T/2,kx,Pi,1.8*Pi, 1.8*Pi], kx])]; Plot[ReIm[expr],{kx,-3.14,3.14}]` which should eliminate the error msgs and show you the plot.  Then change `v[...]:=(..., kx,-Pi,Pi]` to `v[...]:=(..., {kx,-Pi,Pi}]` Try deleting resolved comments to encourage others to help

Comment: The issue in the above code is resolved if I use NIntegrate instead of Integrate.